# Utilizar Storage::url($foo) de laravel en un componente de vuejs?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Habra manera de realizar o mandar a llamar a mi archivo con vuejs?

tengo esto

```
    <template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 animated fadeIn">
            <div class="mb-12 card ">
                <div class="card-body text-center">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <select class="form-control col-md-3" v-model="criterio">
                                    <option selected value="anio">Año</option>
                                    <option value="mes">Mes</option>
                                </select>
                                <input type="text" v-model="buscar" @keyup.enter="listarEma(buscar, criterio)" class="form-control" placeholder="Texto a buscar">
                                <button type="submit" @click="listarEma(buscar, criterio)" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Buscar</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="mb-0 table table-hover table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Mes</th>
                                <th>Anio</th>
                                <th>S.M.G.V.</th>
                                <th>U.M.A.</th>
                                <th>Cotizaciones</th>
                                <th>PDF</th>
                                <th>Subido el:</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr v-for="ema in emaData" :key="ema.id">
                                <th v-text="ema.mes"></th>
                                <td v-text="ema.anio"></td>
                                <td v-text="ema.smgv"></td>
                                <td v-text="ema.uma"></td>
                                <td v-text="ema.cotizaciones">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a :href="'storage/'+ema.pdf"> LINK</a> //aqui el storage!
                                </td>
                                <td>{{ ema.created_at | moment("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY") }}</td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                emaData: [],
                criterio: 'anio',
                buscar: ''
            }
        },
        methods: {
            listarEma(buscar, criterio){
                let me = this;
                var url = '/emas/listar?buscar=' + buscar + '&criterio=' + criterio;
                axios.get(url).then(res => {
                    me.emaData = res.data;
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                })
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.listarEma(this.buscar, this.criterio);
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Obvio en larave blade funciona perfecto.

Comment: Cuál es el problema con eso que estás haciendo?

Comment: la imagen la guardo con el metodo `store()` en blade lo puedo mandar a llamar el archivo o la imagen con el metodo ` Storage::url($ema->pdf);` pero la pregunta fue como puedo traer ese file o imagen si estan en la carpeta storage, con el codigo que tengo ahorita no funciona ya que agrega primero `public`

Comment: No puedes usar Storage facade en un componente vue. Lo que puedes hacer es devolver desde esa api a la que llamas con axios la url en vez del path.

Comment: con un accesor podria funcionar? o una peticion por axios seria la unica manera?

Comment: "con un accesor podria funcionar?" > Creo que lo haría con un resource, depende de cómo sea el método que devuelve los datos que obtienes con axios. Dale una leída a https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources . O si agregas a la pregunta el método y el modelo eloquent que usas para devolver los datos puedo agregar una respuesta.

Comment: "o una peticion por axios seria la unica manera? " > No hay una única manera de hacer las cosas, pero para este caso, creo que sería lo más indicado. Otra que se me ocurre es que le pases los datos en una prop, pero no sería muy limpio.